# Linker error on device only

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, linker-errors, dropbox

Im getting the follwoing error when compiling for my device

`File is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/xxx/Desktop/xxxxxxx/DropboxSDK.framework/DropboxSDK for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

Ive checked all .m files are linked and all ok, why is it only doing this on device and what does the compiler want to stop it complaining?

Comment: I don't know the fix because I don't use that library but the complaint is about DropboxSDK.framework, so you should probably focus on details of linking it rather than your own files.

Comment: It appears to be saying that something in your build is not compiled for an armv7s architecture, and the device you're installing on needs files compiled for that architecture.  (This is a confusing mess, I know -- I always ask another guy for advice on this sort of thing, after unsuccessfully muddling over it for half an hour.)

Comment: Do you use any third party lib that was build on previous version of iOS6?

Comment: Ive picked this up from another developer, No lib that refers to Dropbox, the adhoc build and runs fine they sent me,runs fine on simulator, just no go on my device

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"armv7s" is the instruction set supported by the new ARM processor in the iPhone 5. Xcode 4.5 by default generates binaries for armv7 and armv7s.

The linker error means that your app is compiled for armv7 and armv7s (and i386 for the Simulator), but is linked to the DropboxSDK framework which does not contain armv7s code.

So you have the following options:

- Download and install the latest DropboxSDK framework. According to the [CHANGELOG](https://www.dropbox.com/static/developers/CHANGELOG-objc.txt), iPhone 5 support has been added.
- Compile your app for "armv7" only. This is configured in the "Architectures" of the "Build Settings" of your target.

You said that "No lib that refers to Dropbox". But there must be some reference to that library, otherwise the linker would not complain. You can check that in the "Link Binary with Libraries" section of the "Build Phases" tab of your target settings.

Comment: You sir are gent and a scholar! Thanks, downloading the new Dropbox SDK sorted it. Plus one for clear and concise answer.  Thank you